# How to fix grub to boot Mac OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, boot

I change boot order on my macbook in accordance with this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000934/trouble-with-dual-boot-ubuntu-after-update-mac-os-yosemite/26433930#26433930.

But... now I have problem with booting Mac OS X Yosemite. I have error message: error file'/mach_kernel' not found. etc How to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: May be problem not in grub.cfg

This is grub.cfg:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt4'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  82c59491-1ad6-4429-ba55-5ee31bfca073
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 82c59491-1ad6-4429-ba55-5ee31bfca073
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-82c59491-1ad6-4429-ba55-5ee31bfca073' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt4'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  82c59491-1ad6-4429-ba55-5ee31bfca073
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 82c59491-1ad6-4429-ba55-5ee31bfca073
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-37-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=82c59491-1ad6-4429-ba55-5ee31bfca073 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-37-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-82c59491-1ad6-4429-ba55-5ee31bfca073' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-37-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-37-generic-advanced-82c59491-1ad6-4429-ba55-5ee31bfca073' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  82c59491-1ad6-4429-ba55-5ee31bfca073
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 82c59491-1ad6-4429-ba55-5ee31bfca073
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-37-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-37-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=82c59491-1ad6-4429-ba55-5ee31bfca073 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-37-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-37-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-37-generic-recovery-82c59491-1ad6-4429-ba55-5ee31bfca073' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  82c59491-1ad6-4429-ba55-5ee31bfca073
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 82c59491-1ad6-4429-ba55-5ee31bfca073
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-37-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-37-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=82c59491-1ad6-4429-ba55-5ee31bfca073 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-37-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Mac OS X (32-bit) (on /dev/sda2)' --class osx --class darwin --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-xnu-32-275857f348fe4504'  {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod hfsplus
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  275857f348fe4504
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 275857f348fe4504
    fi
        load_video
        set do_resume=0
        if [ /var/vm/sleepimage -nt10 / ]; then
           if xnu_resume /var/vm/sleepimage; then
             set do_resume=1
           fi
        fi
        if [ $do_resume = 0 ]; then
           xnu_uuid 275857f348fe4504 uuid
           if [ -f /Extra/DSDT.aml ]; then
              acpi -e /Extra/DSDT.aml
           fi
           if [ /kernelcache -nt /System/Library/Extensions ]; then
              xnu_kernel /kernelcache boot-uuid=${uuid} rd=*uuid
           else
              xnu_kernel /mach_kernel boot-uuid=${uuid} rd=*uuid
              if [ /System/Library/Extensions.mkext -nt /System/Library/Extensions ]; then
                xnu_mkext /System/Library/Extensions.mkext
              else
                xnu_kextdir /System/Library/Extensions
              fi
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/Extensions.mkext ]; then
              xnu_mkext /Extra/Extensions.mkext
           fi
           if [ -d /Extra/Extensions ]; then
              xnu_kextdir /Extra/Extensions
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/devprop.bin ]; then
              xnu_devprop_load /Extra/devprop.bin
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/splash.jpg ]; then
              insmod jpeg
              xnu_splash /Extra/splash.jpg
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/splash.png ]; then
              insmod png
              xnu_splash /Extra/splash.png
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/splash.tga ]; then
              insmod tga
              xnu_splash /Extra/splash.tga
           fi
        fi
}
menuentry 'Mac OS X (64-bit) (on /dev/sda2)' --class osx --class darwin --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-xnu-64-275857f348fe4504'  {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod hfsplus
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  275857f348fe4504
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 275857f348fe4504
    fi
        load_video
        set do_resume=0
        if [ /var/vm/sleepimage -nt10 / ]; then
           if xnu_resume /var/vm/sleepimage; then
             set do_resume=1
           fi
        fi
        if [ $do_resume = 0 ]; then
           xnu_uuid 275857f348fe4504 uuid
           if [ -f /Extra/DSDT.aml ]; then
              acpi -e /Extra/DSDT.aml
           fi
           if [ /kernelcache -nt /System/Library/Extensions ]; then
              xnu_kernel64 /kernelcache boot-uuid=${uuid} rd=*uuid
           else
              xnu_kernel64 /mach_kernel boot-uuid=${uuid} rd=*uuid
              if [ /System/Library/Extensions.mkext -nt /System/Library/Extensions ]; then
                xnu_mkext /System/Library/Extensions.mkext
              else
                xnu_kextdir /System/Library/Extensions
              fi
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/Extensions.mkext ]; then
              xnu_mkext /Extra/Extensions.mkext
           fi
           if [ -d /Extra/Extensions ]; then
              xnu_kextdir /Extra/Extensions
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/devprop.bin ]; then
              xnu_devprop_load /Extra/devprop.bin
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/splash.jpg ]; then
              insmod jpeg
              xnu_splash /Extra/splash.jpg
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/splash.png ]; then
              insmod png
              xnu_splash /Extra/splash.png
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/splash.tga ]; then
              insmod tga
              xnu_splash /Extra/splash.tga
           fi
        fi
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Comment: it would help to include your grub configuration

Answer (score 2):

This might not be very helpful but, holding Option (or Alt) while powering up will normally give you Apple's own boot manager, from you should be able to boot into Yosemite.

Then you could reinstall rEFInd using the `./install.sh --alldrivers` installation (as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150670/install-refind-on-os-x-10-10-yosemite)), or the official rEFInd guidelines (found [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/yosemite.html), or as an answer on the previous link) which I have also used to perform a fresh installation of Ubuntu, with dual-booting working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with holding down the option key while you start up. However, I have found that if you hold down command + option + r + p when you are starting up, wait for the two "ding"s and restart, it will automatically boot into whatever Mac system you are using. I have MacOS 10.12.4, and it works fine now.

Also, if you start up using the option key, you can go into system preferances-->startup disk and select your operating system, it will boot directly into it.